# Reduced Primary Decomposition in Almost Clean Rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

**Theorem 2.3**. For a commutative ring $R$ the following conditions
are equivalent.

1. $R$ is an indecomposable almost clean ring.
2. For $x\in R$, either $x$ or $x−1$ is regular.
3. For (prime) ideals $I$ and $J$ of $R$ consisting of zero divisors,$I+J=R$.

**Corollary 4**. Suppose that $R$ has a reduced primary decomposition
$0=Q_1∩···∩Q_n$ where $Q_i$ is $P_i$-primary. Then $R$ is an indecomposable
almost clean ring if and only if $Q_i+Q_j\ne R$ (or equivalently, $P_i+P_j\ne R$).

Found this on [Weakly Clean Rings and Almost Clean Rings by Ahn & Anderson](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/38371099_Weakly_Clean_Rings_and_Almost_Clean_Rings).

I believe that proving Corollary 4 is using Theorem 2.3 (1) and (3), i.e. $P_i$ and $P_j$ must consist of zero divisors. But I dont have any idea about how to obtain these conditions.
**Question** (edited):
Is if $P_i$ is a prime ideal then $P_i⊆Z(R)$? Or is it because $0=Q_1∩ ... ∩Q_n$ then $P_i⊆Z(R)$. Any explanation about how prove Corollary 4?

Comment: By regular, do you mean that $x$ is not a zero divisor and not a unit?

Comment: Do you mean the Theorem 2.3 (2)?

Comment: Exactly. What is your definition of a regular element of a ring?

Comment: An element of a ring is called regular if it is not zero divisor.

Comment: So, it is possible that $xR = R?$